# I am trying to have the X-axis with strings instead of numbers: The Strings are ("Movies","TV Show"), and the Y axis filled with numbers till 8000

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

As you read in the title, that's what I'm having problems with, and not only that, but I need to plot it as a bar graph with two separate bars, one for Movie, and one for TV Show, this is because i want to show the difference between how many movies there are than TV shows.

```
substr = 'Movie'
substr1 = 'TV Show'

print('This are how many movies are in this dataframe:',netflix_df.type.str.count(substr).sum())
print('This are how many TV Show are in this dataframe:',netflix_df.type.str.count(substr1).sum())
```

output:

```
This are how many movies are in this dataframe: 5377
This are how many TV Show are in this dataframe: 2410
```

### Part in which I'm having problem with

```
x_ticks_labels = ['Movie','TV Shows']
plt.title('Movies/TV Shows')
plt.hist([netflix_df.type.str.count(substr).sum(),netflix_df.type.str.count(substr1).sum()],
        bins = np.arange(x_ticks_labels),
        stacked = True);
plt.legend(['TV Show','Movies']);
```

Comment: If you want just a bar chart with two bars, one for movies and one for TV, it will be plt.bar(). If it is a histogram in the current code, the section will not be a string. What is your desired output?

Comment: My desired output is the y axis being the number of releases of Shows/Movies and the X axis being the Movies and TV Shows, so Movies should have a bar graph all the way up to 5377 and TV shows all the way up to 2410